# How to iterate through all files in sftp folder in Microsoft Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

steps i already did using SFTP connector (how can i access files while looping through list files in folder in azure logic app):

1. I added foreach loop
2. I added list files in folder
3. I passed Body as parameter in foreach loop
4. then i added action to create new file with new name for all files.
5. but i am not able to get file name and content while iterating sftp folder using foreach loop?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see example image, showing the logic app design. I am iterating sftp folder posting file content to http end point:

[image: Logic App Image]